# Error message during installing caffe command 'make all' about "caffe::cudnn::dataType<double>::zero"

Tags: c++, makefile, caffe

I ran

```
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
make all
```

as suggested on the website to complete the installation. I use Ubuntu 15.04 with CUDA and atlas.

The error messages showed as follows

> CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin
>         CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin
>         CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
>         CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin
>         CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
>         CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin
>         CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
>         CXX/LD -o .build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin' failed
>       make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin] Error 1
>       make:**  正在等待未完成的任务....
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin' failed
>       make:  **[.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin] Error 1
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin' failed
>       make:**  [.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin] Error 1
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin' failed
>       make:  **[.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin] Error 1
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin' failed
>       make:**  [.build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin] Error 1
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:624: recipe for target '.build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin' failed
>       make:  **[.build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin] Error 1
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/caffe.bin' failed
>       make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::zero’未定义的引用
>       .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so：对‘caffe::cudnn::dataType::one’未定义的引用
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin' failed
>       make: *** [.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin] Error 1

Comment: Caffe recommands OpenBLAS since It presumably increases performance over ATLAS, and revises "BLAS := open" in Makefile.config before making all $((..)).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your case, but my solution was to uncomment the line with

```
# USE_OPENCV := 0
OPENCV_VERSION := 3
```

in 'Makefile.config' since I was with OpenCV version > 3.0.

make clean and make all -j $(($(nproc) + 1)) with all your processor. It should be fine afterwards.